# Trying to learn how loops work, what is going wrong?

Tags: python

The question is :

Given a string, return a string where for every char in the original, there are two chars.

This is my attempt:

```
def double_char(str):
    n = 0
    for x in range(0, len(str)):
        return 2*str[n]
        n = n+1
```

When I run it, it only returns 2 versions of the first letter and doesn't loop properly. So for double_char(Hello) it just returns HH.

What is going wrong? Thanks in advance for any help, sorry for the really beginner question.

Comment: `return` *returns* control to the caller once reached, exiting your `for` loop prematurely

Comment: what would I put in its place then? Because if I use print codingbat tells me that it wants the code returned.

Comment: @thornbird Above the loop have a string that you add each duplicated letter to, then return the string after the loop.

Comment: first build the string and then return it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return is causing your function to return in the first iteration so it just returns 2 of the first letter.

What you may have intended to write was something like

```
def double_char(s):
    n = 0
    r = ''
    for x in range(0, len(s)):
        r += 2*s[n]
        n = n+1

    return r
```

Building a string incrementally that is just 2 of each character.

A neater refactor of that function (without duplicating the other answer by using a comprehension) is

```
def double_char(s):

    r = ''
    for c in s:
        r += 2*c

    return r
```

You also should not use `str` as a variable name. It is a built in type and you are hiding that by defining a variable called `str`.

Comment: How come you used c without defining it? Or is c meant to be short for chars? Which I'm guessing is an inbuilt type?

Comment: No it's not inbuilt. See `for c in s:`. This means run a loop over `s` and give the name `c` to the item in `s` we are currently looking at. You can call it what you like. I just thought s=string c=char are sensible short names.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. Thank you again :)

Answer (score 1):

`return` *returns* control to the caller once reached, thus exiting your `for` loop prematurely.

Here's a simpler way to do that with [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

```
def double_char(s):
    return ''.join(i*2 for i in s)
```

---

```
>>> s = 'Hello'
>>> double_char(s)
'HHeelllloo'
```

---

Do not use `str` as name to avoid shadowing the builtin `str` function.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a different way to solving the question.

```
def double_char(str):
  new_str = ""
  for i in range(len(str)):
    new_str += (str[i]*2)
  return new_str

double_char('Hello')
'HHeelllloo'
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
def double_char(str):

    string = ''
    for i in range(len(str)):
      string += str[i] * 2
      i += 1

    return string
```